# Comparing the data of 2 linked lists! (Java)

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, compare, equals

My project is to see if a user inputted string is a palindrome or not. Firstly, the string is to be put into a Linked list and then copied into a second linked list where I reverse the list completely in order to compare them.

the linked list is my own class as well all the methods within it. I have confirmed that the linked list works as does the reverse method.

Where i run into problems is when i try and compare the 2 from the beginning of the lists.
This is what i've tried:

```
package palindromes;
import data_structures.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Palindrome
{
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s)
    {
        if (s.length() <= 1) // base case
            return true;
        String originalList = s.replaceAll("[\\W]", "").toLowerCase();

        LinkedList<Character> list1 = new LinkedList<Character>();
        LinkedList<Character> rlist = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < originalList.length(); i++)
        {
            list1.addLast(originalList.charAt(i));
        }
        rlist = list1;
        rlist.reverse();
        Iterator<Character> l1 = list1.iterator();
        Iterator<Character> l2 = rlist.iterator();
        while (l1.hasNext() && l2.hasNext())
        {
            if (l1.next() != l1.next())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I try to iterate through both lists in the while loop but when i go to test the data of the nodes it is incorrect.

Please let me know if you need added information or clarification.

My question is how do i fix my code so that i am able to compare the lists sequentially to see if the inputted string is a palindrome or not?

Comment: Never compare objects with `==` if you want to compare equality - `==` compares object identity!

Comment: You don't have to place `\\W` inside `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in following way:

```
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

     list.add("a");
     list.add("b");
     list.add("c");
     list.add("c");
     list.add("b");
     list.add("a");
     int size = list.size();
     for(int i = 0; i<size/2; i++)
     {
         if(list.get(i) == list.get(size - 1))
            System.out.println("list is palindrome");

     }
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was making my own get method and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
rlist = list1;
```

is the problem. Both rlist and list1 are just two references to the same List.

replace it with

```
rlist = new LinkedList<Character>(list1);
```

this will create `new List` and copy all the elements in the `list1` to that `new list`. `rlist` is referring to the `new list` while `list1` refers to the `old list`.